# How to get user related data in sharepoint + c#

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I as a administrator want to access the list of files/folders for a given user.

Use case:

1. the user would send his userName/UserId to me and in back-end i would use administrators credentials to get all lists.
2. I want to get only the list of files which is shared with the incoming userName/UserId. like a where clause.

I am stuck on this.any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you dealing with (e.g. 2007, 2010, 2013, O365) and is it on-premises or cloud hosted?

Comment: 2013 currently it is on-premises